# Fill login details of external site

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, alert, mkdocs

I have application with angular where I have an input:

```
<p> <a href="redirect()" target="_blank">Open documentation</a></p>
```

which calls method:

```
    redirect() {
window.open(this.documentationUrl, '_blank');}
```

`this.documentationUrl` holds the link of documentation (let's say docs.com) site and is made with `Mkdocs`. On click, alert pops up asking for Username and Password. Is it possible to fill that alert which pops up? And which side it should be done on *angular* or *Mkdocs*? I know it should be possible but I have no idea how and where to begin.

I've tried getting html content:

```
 ngOnInit() {
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('x-forwarded-host', 'foo');
this.http.get('https://docs.com/').subscribe(response => {
  console.log( response.json());debugger;
});}
```

However I get: *401 Authorization Required
nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)*. If I would manually go to the website alert would popup, but now I don't get it in the response.

also I tried `<iframe id="iframe" src="https://docs.com/"></iframe>`
and

```
let iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
```

but that doesn't seem to get the alert either

Comment: Well, you will probably want something like [this](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) to provide your interface with a modal, however my inkling is you are in a bit over your head. What have you tried?

Comment: Edited my answer